# Ruby: What is the best way to parse xml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xml-parsing

I was in doubt what is the best way to use XML in Ruby, could you help me please?
I saw that Ruby has XmlMarkup, there are other options as well?

thank you

Comment: `Nokogiri` of-course!! some flavors [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125850/issue-parsing-xml-with-ruby/20125971#20125971)

Comment: http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/reading_huge_xml-rb/
I also found ox is 5 times faster than nokogiri while reading a large xml.
Plus I have a wrapper written which simply allows you to search through large xml using ox, it allows you to iterate with specified element.
https://gist.github.com/amolpujari/5966431

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to parse XML, I strongly recommend checking out [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) - it's a gem you can include that is very powerful at parsing XML.

Comment: Thanks, helped me choose an option

Comment: If you are unsure what gem to choose when there are different options, than the Ruby Toolbox is a good site to investigate popularity and find up-to-date gems: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/nokogiri